# IONIC 3 - WKWebview CORS issues

Tags: ios, post, cors, ionic3, wkwebview

In order to solve statusbar issues in IOS 11, IONIC team has become the WKWebview as default in the recent release. Since then, I am having CORS issues... I have tried many ways to sort this out, but none of them has had any effect. Although the Native HTTP plugin seems to solve CORS issues, it does not work with the XML content type. I also attempted to use the following plugin: https://github.com/sneas/ionic-native-http-connection-backend

But I am still getting the following error:
[image]

Code:

```
public sendRequest(sufix, json) {           

    console.log(json);
    let headers = new Headers({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/xml', 
        'livefacilities-apptoken': APPTOKEN
    });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ 'headers': headers });
    let xml = this.jsonToXml(json);
    console.log(xml);
    return this.http.post(URL+sufix, xml, options)
        .timeout(TIMEOUT_REQUEST*1000)
        .do(this.logResponse)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);   

}
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

A solution which has always worked for me is adding following headers in your API/WEB SERVICE file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
```

I also faced the same issue in our app, you can resolve it by using ionic native http plugin and make sure that you use this plugin HTTP.post method in your js not your normal http.post.

As per official documentation of ionic: "If it is not an possibility to implement or configure CORS in the server, there is a native plugin that can “proxy” the HTTP requests using native code, so CORS can be completely bypassed"

Please try this.

Comment: Hi Krish, thank you for your answer. How can I sort this out once I am using XML rather than JSON? As far as I know, the native plugin only has support for JSON, am I right?

Comment: Hi @PedroDurek another solution to resolve this pre-flight response issue is adding following headers in your API/WEB SERVICE file:

 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following lines to config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <access origin="http://localhost:8080" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
</platform>
```